# Not able to render the html after ajax call in Rails 3 and ruby 1.9.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am uploading image using filedrop.js. Code in application.js file looks like this:-

```
 $(".droparea").each(function(event){
  var game_id = $(this).attr('id')
  $(this).filedrop({
  maxfilezsize: 5,
  maxfiles: 1,
  dataType: "script",
  paraname :"custom_game[file]"
  url: "/game_plans/'+$(".dropbox").attr("rel")+'/games/'+game_id+/upload_file.js"
  })
 }
```

This part is working fine. I am getting into the proper action with proper parameters.

```
def upload_file
  # NOTE Upload_file action has been explicity written for the file upload using drag and drop
  @custom_game = CustomGame.find_or_initialize_by_id(params[:id])
  @game_plan = GamePlan.find(params[:game_plan_id])
  @custom_game.update_attributes(params[:custom_game])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

upload_file.js.erb:

```
$("#<%=  @custom_game%>_file").html(<%= @custom_game.file%>);
```

But in view of respective action i.e. upload_file.js.erb I am not able to execute any of the javascript commands , whereas ruby commands are working properly. And in log also it says that the partial has been successfully rendered.

My log shows:-

```
(101.8ms)  COMMIT
Rendered activities/upload_file.js.erb (0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 379ms (Views: 10.8ms | ActiveRecord: 106.9ms)
```

I have no clue where I am making the mistake. No jquery command is being executed in upload_file.js.erb , but ruby commands are working properly.

Comment: Instead of showing the code that *does* work, please show the code that *doesn't* work. I.e. your controller and upload_file.js.erb.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mischa. I have mentioned the code of the controller as well as the js.erb file. Please take a look.

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but you should use [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) to prevent problems with quotes and line brakes.

Comment: No that did not solved the problem. I guess the problem may lie in the way i implemented [filedrop.js](https://github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop).

Comment: can you execute the javascript returned by `upload_file.js` in a browser console without errors?

Comment: In firefox I took the response and executed in its console it showed me no error\

Comment: What did the response look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#<%=  @custom_game%>_file").html(<%= @custom_game.file%>);
```

`<%=  @custom_game %>` returns the CustomGame object, where I think you ment to use @custom_game.title or something.
jQuery cant find $("#<#CustomGame:834793746>_file") so html is not replaced.

You might want to try the javascript in a console to check if it executes manually (using chrome's dev tools myself)

Comment: Yeah I was wondering about that too. Also `<%= @custom_game.file%>` should probably be in quotes: `.html('<%= @custom_game.file%>');`